# Lean: what does the syntax `variable [ring R]` mean?

Tags: lean, lean3

I have written a simple Lean program, inspired by things I found here and there, which compiles as shown in the [web editor](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=import%20algebra.ring.basic%20%0A%0Avariable%20R%20%3A%20Type%0Avariable%20%5Bring%20R%5D%0A%0Atheorem%20first_theorem%28a%20%3A%20R%29%3A%20-%28-a%29%20%3D%20a%20%3A%3D%0Acalc%0A%20%20-%28-a%29%20%3D%20-%28-a%29%20%2B%200%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20by%20rw%20add_zero%0A%20%20...%20%20%20%3D%200%20%2B%20-%28-a%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20by%20rw%20add_comm%0A%20%20...%20%20%20%3D%20%28a%20-%20a%29%20%2B%20%28-%28-a%29%29%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20by%20rw%20sub_self%0A%20%20...%20%20%20%3D%20%28a%20%2B%20%28-a%29%29%20%2B%20%28-%28-a%29%29%20%20%3A%20by%20rw%20sub_eq_add_neg%0A%20%20...%20%20%20%3D%20a%20%2B%20%28%28-a%29%20%2B%20-%28-a%29%29%20%20%20%20%3A%20by%20rw%20add_assoc%0A%20%20...%20%20%20%3D%20a%20%2B%20%28-a%20-%20%28-a%29%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20by%20rw%20sub_eq_add_neg%0A%20%20...%20%20%20%3D%20a%20%2B%200%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20by%20rw%20sub_self%0A%20%20...%20%20%20%3D%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20by%20rw%20add_zero%20%0A):

```
import algebra.ring.basic 

variable R : Type
variable [ring R]

theorem first_theorem(a : R): -(-a) = a :=
calc
  -(-a) = -(-a) + 0             : by rw add_zero
  ...   = 0 + -(-a)             : by rw add_comm
  ...   = (a - a) + (-(-a))     : by rw sub_self
  ...   = (a + (-a)) + (-(-a))  : by rw sub_eq_add_neg
  ...   = a + ((-a) + -(-a))    : by rw add_assoc
  ...   = a + (-a - (-a))       : by rw sub_eq_add_neg
  ...   = a + 0                 : by rw sub_self
  ...   = a                     : by rw add_zero
```

(Sub-question: is there a way to make the web editor show something in the right panel when the theorem is correctly proven? It bothers me that it stays blank...)

My question is basic but I couldn't find an answer in the doc: what does the syntax `variable [ring R]` mean?
I understand that it somehow declares `R` to be a ring, but why the brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets means that `Ring R` is an *implicit* argument, meaning the Lean will find it by itself when needed. This why you didn't need to give it a name nor to explicitly mention it in your proof. You can learn more about this in the [TPIL](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/dependent_type_theory.html?highlight=implicit#implicit-arguments).

Comment: instance implicit, no?

Comment: Yes, it is an instance, so it is found by typeclass search, not by unification.